# How do I reverse sudo apt-mark hold linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: kernel, updates

I ran

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

because of hardware issues.

After getting new hardware, how do I reverse this command to auto update kernel.

Answer (score 4):

The reverse command is

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: WOW, that simple thank you